# Remote Desktop switching control between client & host - How?

Tags: xrdp, remmina

Remmina remote desktop tools does not have "Give Control," "Pass Control," or something similar.
Ubuntu 22.04... all updates... etc. Client makes good connection...
I'm a newbie... so I missed some setting?
Thanks in advance for any leads...

Comment: Not very familiar with Remmina, but doesn't the client automatically have the ability to control the desktop? You can "grab keyboard" or put the client in read-only mode, but I don't see any option for switching control. What exactly are you trying to do that you can't do without a "give control" option?